# Constraints in type family instances

Tags: haskell, type-families

I'm exploring type families in Haskell, trying to establish the complexity of type-level functions I can define. I want to define a closed type-level version of `mod`, something like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances #-}
import GHC.TypeLits

type family Mod (m :: Nat) (n :: Nat) :: Nat where
  n <= m => Mod m n = Mod (m - n) n
  Mod m n = m
```

However, the compiler (GHC 7.10.2) rejects this, as the constraint in the first equation isn't permitted. How do guards at the value-level translate to the type level? Is this even possible in Haskell currently?

Comment: Perhaps there's an `If` type level function? I think I saw that used somewhere, but I'm not a library expert...

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right, `If` exists in [Data.Type.Bool](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Type-Bool.html).

Comment: Following up on this, I managed to rewrite `Mod` using the type-level `If`, which compiled successfully. However, any attempt to reduce a term of the form `Mod m n` resulted in a stack overflow exception. Tweaking the _-freduction-depth_ option showed me that GHC was prioritising expanding the `m - n` part of the expression, without realising that this may never be possible. I'll have to look further in the _DataKinds_ extension to understand more of the behaviour.

Comment: That's very interesting. From your report, it seems that type-level `If` is eager on all its arguments, which looks wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an answer (I don't think there even is one possible yet), but for the benefit of other people (like me) trying to retrace OPs steps in comments. The following compiles, but using it quickly results in a stack overflow.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances #-}
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Type.Bool

type family Mod (m :: Nat) (n :: Nat) :: Nat where
  Mod m n = If (n <=? m) (Mod (m - n) n) m
```

The reason is that [`If`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Bool.html#t:If) itself is just a regular type family and the behavior of type-families is to start by expanding their type arguments (eager in a sense) before using those in the right hand side. The unfortunate result in this case is that `Mod (m - n) n` gets expanded even if `n <=? m` is false, hence the stack overflow.

For exactly the same reason, the logical operators in [`Data.Type.Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Bool.html) do not short circuit. Given

```
type family Bottom :: Bool where Bottom = Bottom
```

We can see that `False && Bottom` and `True || Bottom` both hang.

## EDIT

Just in case the OP is just interested in a type family with the required behavior (and not just the more general problem of having guards in type families) there *is* a way to express `Mod` in a way that terminates:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances #-}
import GHC.TypeLits

type Mod m n = Mod1 m n 0 m

type family Mod1 (m :: Nat) (n :: Nat) (c :: Nat) (acc :: Nat) :: Nat where
  Mod1 m n n acc = Mod1 m n 0 m
  Mod1 0 n c acc = acc
  Mod1 m n c acc = Mod1 (m - 1) n (c + 1) acc
```