# Writing AbsDiff for GHC.TypeLits.Nat

Tags: haskell

With Peano-style type-level naturals, it's fairly easy to write an absolute difference type-level function (aka type family):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, StandaloneKindSignatures, TypeFamilies #-}

module Nat where

data Nat = Z | S Nat

type AbsDiff :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
type family AbsDiff x y where
  AbsDiff x Z = x
  AbsDiff Z y = y
  AbsDiff (S x) (S y) = AbsDiff x y
```

[`GHC.TypeLits.Nat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:Nat) is a more efficient way to represent and manipulate the type-level naturals, compared to a unary representation. However, I don't see how to define `AbsDiff` for `GHC.TypeLits.Nat` without resorting to unary subtraction. [`GHC.TypeLits.CmpNat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:CmpNat) exists, and I could imagine using it like this (hypothetical syntax):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, StandaloneKindSignatures, TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module Nat

import GHC.TypeLits

type family AbsDiff x y where
  CmpNat x y ~ LT => AbsDiff x y = y - x
  CmpNat x y ~ EQ => AbsDiff x y = 0
  CmpNat x y ~ GT => AbsDiff x y = x - y
```

But there appears to be [no way to constrain a type family instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550959/constraints-in-type-family-instances). This makes sense, as [constraints don't guide typeclass resolution](http://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/instances.html#instance-declarations-and-resolution), and type families presumably work similarly.

Is there any way to write an efficient `AbsDiff` for `GHC.TypeLits.Nat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper to control evaluation.  Given:

```
type family Minus x y where
  Minus 1 0 = 1
  Minus 0 1 = Minus 0 1  -- infinite loop

type family AbsDiff x y where
  AbsDiff x y = If (x <=? y) (Minus y x) (Minus x y)

type family AbsDiff' x y where
  AbsDiff' x y = AbsDiff1 (x <=? y) x y
type family AbsDiff1 c x y where
  AbsDiff1 True x y = Minus y x
  AbsDiff1 False x y = Minus x y
```

resolution of `AbsDiff 0 1` and `AbsDiff 1 0` loop, as you expected, but `AbsDiff' 0 1` and `AbsDiff' 1 0` work fine, so this definition should work for you:

```
type family AbsDiff' x y where
    AbsDiff' x y = AbsDiff1 (x <=? y) x y
type family AbsDiff1 c x y where
    AbsDiff1 True x y = y - x
    AbsDiff1 False x y = x - y
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a rather uncomfortable workaround involving [`Data.Type.Bool.If`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Bool.html#t:If). It's uncomfortable because `If` is strict rather than lazy; if `0 - 1 :: Nat` took much work to resolve, or if it were an error rather than irreducible, then this wouldn't be a solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, PolyKinds, StandaloneKindSignatures, TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances #-}

module Nat where

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Type.Bool

type AbsDiff :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
type family AbsDiff x y where
  AbsDiff x y = If (x <=? y) (y - x) (x - y)
```

Comment: Are you sure `If` is strict? I thought GHC didn't specify an evaluation order for its type-level computations.

Comment: @DanielWagner well, I suppose the crux is that is _doesn't specify evaluation order to be lazy_, in the way that `if` / `?` constructs are specified in just about any language.